# lightning:treeGrid Conditional Action(button) column

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, slds, spring18

We are trying to build a Hierarchical view of records using `lightning:treeGrid` and based on value from a field in each record, the button in action(button) column should change.

Let's Say we are passing a list of custom Object records with a field as `status__c` to treeGrid.
In each row, if the `status__c` of record is "Completed", the button column should display a button as "Proceed", 
if the `status__c` of record not "Completed", the button column should display a button as "Redo".

Is it possible with `lightning:treeGrid`?

Any ideas or solution on this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a need to do the same thing and found a solution based on another [answer dealing with datatables](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/212676/lightningdatatable-dynamically-disable-rowactions)

The same method happens to work with treeGrid and not just to change attributes, but you can also use it to change the actions placed on click.  I have a working dynamic action list for each type of row on my treeGrid component.  Here's a simplified bit of code to get you started for your specific use case:

### Component

```
<!-- ATTRIBUTES -->
<aura:attribute name="gridCols" type="Object[]" />
<aura:attribute name="gridData" type="Object[]" />

<!-- HANDLERS -->
<aura:handler name="init" value="{! this }" action="{! c.doInit }"/>

<!-- DISPLAY -->
<lightning:layout>
  <lightning:treeGrid columns="{! v.gridCols }"
                      data="{! v.gridData }"
                      hideCheckboxColumn="true"
                      keyField="id"
                      onrowaction="{!c.onRowSelect}" />
</lightning:layout>
```

### Controller

```
({
  doInit: function(cmp,event,helper){
    //call actions from handler function
    var actions = helper.getRowActions.bind(this, cmp);

    var gridCols = [
        {label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text'},
        {type: 'action', typeAttributes: { rowActions: actions} }
    ];
    cmp.set('v.gridCols',gridCols);

    /*
    var gridData = [];
    ...data building (however you get your data)...
    cmp.set('v.gridData',gridData);
    */
  },
  onRowSelect: function(cmp,event,helper){
    var action = event.getParam('action');
    var row = event.getParam('row');
    switch (action.name) {
        case 'proceed_action':
        //proceed action things to do goes here
          break;
        case 'redo_action':
        //redo action things to do goes here
          break;
    }
})
```

### Helper

```
({
  getRowActions: function(cmp,row,cb){
    //handler function to build actions dynamically
    var actions = [];                        
    if(row.status__c == "Completed"){
        actions = [{label:'Proceed',name:'proceed_action'}];
    }else{
        actions = [{label:'Redo', name:'redo_action'}];
    }
    cb(actions);
  },
})
```

Using this code you can pass in different action lists to different rows based on each row.