# Lightning:datatable dynamically disable rowactions

Tags: lightning-datatable

I have a `lightning:datatable`, which is rendering a set of objects:

```
<lightning:datatable data="{!v.propertyMappings}" 
                           columns="{!v.columns}" 
                           keyField="Id" 
                           onrowaction="{!c.handleRowAction}"
                           hideCheckboxColumn="true" 
                           resizeColumnDisabled="true" />
```

I want to dynamically enable/disable some rows based on an attribute on `Custom_Object__c` that is loaded into `{!v.propertyMappings}`.

I tried adding a `disabled` attribute to the object data when it was loaded in my helper:

```
    var responseValues = response.getReturnValue();
    for (var i = 0; i < responseValues.length; i++) {
      responseValues[i]["disabled"] = true;
    } 
    component.set("v.propertyMappings", responseValues);
```

But it didn't seem to have any effect...?

My row-actions are still available (from `{!v.columns}`):

```
{ type: "action", typeAttributes: { rowActions: actions } }
```

Should I just use another component?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to handle the disabled attribute in your getRowActions handler (you do have one, right?). Here's a self-contained example that demonstrates this.

## Application

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <aura:attribute name="data" type="List" />
    <aura:attribute name="columns" type="List" />

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />

    <div style="height: 300px">
    <lightning:datatable data="{!v.data}"
                         columns="{!v.columns}"
                         keyField="Id"
                         onrowaction="{!c.handleAction}"
                         hideCheckboxColumn="true"
                         resizeColumnDisabled="true" />
    </div>
</aura:application>
```

---

## Controller

```
({
    init: function(component, event, helper) {
        // callback binding
        var actions = helper.getRowActions.bind(this, component);
        // sample data
        component.set("v.data", [
            { Id: "1", intValue: 0 },
            { Id: "2", intValue: 0 },
            { Id: "3", intValue: 0 },
            { Id: "4", intValue: 0 },
            { Id: "5", intValue: 0 },
            { Id: "6", intValue: 0 }
        ]);
        // column data
        component.set("v.columns", [
            { label: "value", fieldName: "intValue", type: "number" },
            { type: "action", typeAttributes: { rowActions: actions }}
        ]);
    },
    // handle action
    handleAction: function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = event.getParam("action"),
            row = event.getParam("row"),
            data = component.get("v.data"),
            rowIndex = data.indexOf(row);
        switch(action.name) {
            case 'inc': data[rowIndex].intValue++;
                break;
        }
        component.set("v.data", data);
    }
})
```

---

## Helper

```
({
    getRowActions: function(component, row, cb) {
        var actions = [];
        actions.push({
            label: "Increment", 
            name: "inc",
            // allow three increments per row
            disabled: row.intValue > 2 });
        cb(actions);
    }
})
```

---

Here, I'm using row-based data to determine if the menu item is disabled or not. This is done dynamically at the moment the menu button is clicked. You can make this as simple or complicated as need be.

Comment: I wonder @sfdcfox if you can explain what you are doing with the `helper.getRowActions.bind` and how it works?

Comment: @ItaiShmida You'll want to read [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). It's not Lightning specific, but rather just a general JavaScript function.

Comment: @sfdcfox can we do the same approach for lightning button that is of type  button.

Comment: @VidhyasagaranMuralidharan you can set the disabled attribute, I believe, but you'll want to check the documentation. Actions should always use an action menu, not a button.

Comment: @sfdcfox Yes got it.I got requirement like i have ten rows with button.based on condition in one row  i need to disable button.So I am curious to know whether we can use helper.getRowActions.bind for that. And I don't find any documentation based on button example.

Comment: @VidhyasagaranMuralidharan No, you can't use getRowActions, because that's used for row actions. However, you can still evaluate based on some data to determine if you need to disable the button (`<lightning:button disabled="{!row.someAttribute}" ... />`). If you're stuck, try asking a new question so we can see the code you've tried so far and where you're stuck.