# Need Help with Lightning Tree Grid: Fetching Parent and Child Records on Button Click

Tags: apex, javascript, aura, lightningtreegrid

I'm currently working on an Aura component that utilizes the Lightning Tree Grid table in Salesforce. My goal is to retrieve both the parent record and its associated child records when a button is clicked, without relying on row selection. Unfortunately, I've encountered a limitation where I can't set up inline editing in the tree grid. Here's my component for reference. I'd greatly appreciate any insights or solutions to achieve this functionality efficiently.

```
<aura:component controller="AllCommissions">

<aura:attribute name="data" type="Object"/>

<aura:attribute name="columns" type="List" />

<aura:attribute name="gridData" type="Object"  />

<aura:attribute name="gridExpandedRows" type="List" access="PRIVATE" />

<aura:attribute name="tableCols1" type="List" />

<aura:attribute name="commissionList" type="List"/>

<aura:method name="fetchSDRsbyDate" action="{!c.fetchSDRcommissionsbyDate}" description="fetchSDRs commissions by date">

<aura:attribute name="showRowNumberColumn" type="Boolean" default="true"/>    

<aura:attribute name="rowNumberOffset" type="Integer" default="10"/>

<aura:attribute name="StartDate" type="date"/>

<aura:attribute name="EndDate" type="date"/>

<aura:attribute name="FromDate" type="String"/>

<aura:attribute name="ToDate" type="String"/>

<aura:attribute name="QueryType" type="String"/>

</aura:method>

<aura:attribute name="approvalStateOptions" type="List" default="[

{ label: 'Approved - Pending Scheduling', value: 'Approved - Pending Scheduling' },

{ label: 'Scheduled - Pending Payment', value: 'Scheduled - Pending Payment' },

{ label: 'Payment Received', value: 'Payment Received' }]" 

/>

<aura:registerEvent name="doneLoadingEvent" type="c:doneLoadingEvent" />

<!-- <aura:registerEvent name="editEvent" type="c:editEvent" /> -->

<aura:attribute name="parentAction" type="Aura.Component"/>

<lightning:accordion

    allowMultipleSectionsOpen="true"

    onsectiontoggle="{! c.handleSectionToggle }"

    activeSectionName="{! v.activeSections }">

    <lightning:accordionSection name="A" label="SDR Monthly Commission"> 

        <div >

            <div>

                <lightning:treeGrid

                columns="{! v.tableCols1 }"

                data="{! v.gridData }"

                onrowaction="{!c.OpenChildEventPopup}"

                keyField="Original SDR"/>

            </div>

        </div>

    </lightning:accordionSection>

</lightning:accordion>

</aura:component>
```

Aura Controller:

```
 OpenChildEventPopup: function (component, event, helper) {

        //var editEvent = component.getEvent("editEvent"); // Define an edit event

        // You can pass data or other information to the parent component here

        // For example, you can include row data from the current context

        console.log('@@@child_Event_Pop_Fired@@@@');

        var action = event.getParam('action');

        var row = event.getParam('row');

        console.log('@@@child_Event' + action.name);

        if (action.name === 'edit') 
        {

          
          var parentRecord = row.SDR;
        

        }
```

Reference:

[image: Output]

Recent updates:

I'm able to fetch parent records and unable to fetch child records

Here is the response added to the component:

```
OpportunityNameLabel: "Michael Noonan"
SDR:"Michael Noonan"
TotalAmount:2500000
TotalCommission: 5000
TotalSum: 5000
    _children:Array(1)
        0: 
        Approval_Verified_Stage__c: null
        Approver__c: null
        Id: "006Ec000007Z2pLIAS"
        OpportunityNameLabel: "Test_Status"
        SDR: "/lightning/r/Opportunity/006Ec000007Z2pLIAS/view"
        StageName: "Exec Recap"
        TotalAmount: 2500000
        TotalCommission: 5000
        Verified_Approved_Timestamp__c: "2023-09-25"
```

[image: JSON Response from log]

Answer (score 1):

Inline Editing and sorting is not supported with tree-grid. Only below features are supported.

- Displaying and formatting of columns with appropriate data types
- Header-level actions
- Row-level actions
- Resizing of columns
- Selecting of rows
- Text wrapping and clipping

```
<lightning:treeGrid columns="{! v.gridColumns }" data="{! v.gridData }"
   onrowaction="{!c.OpenChildEventPopup}" keyField="Original SDR"/>
```

```
init : function(cmp){

        var columns = [
            {
                type: 'text',
                fieldName: 'accountName',
                label: 'Account Name'
            },
            {
                type: 'number',
                fieldName: 'employees',
                label: 'Employees'
            },
            {
                type: 'phone',
                fieldName: 'phone',
                label: 'Phone Number'
            },
            {
                type: 'url',
                fieldName: 'accountOwner',
                label: 'Account Owner',
                typeAttributes: {
                    label: { fieldName: 'accountOwnerName' }
                }
            },
            {type: 'action', typeAttributes: { rowActions: [{label:'Proceed',name:'proceed_action'}]} }
        ];
        cmp.set('v.gridColumns', columns);
},
OpenChildEventPopup: function(cmp,event,helper){
    let action = event.getParam('action');
    let row = event.getParam('row');
// Write your Logic Here
}
```

[image: Logs]

Reference : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:treeGrid/documentation

[lightning:treeGrid Conditional Action(button) column](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/208127/lightningtreegrid-conditional-actionbutton-column)

Comment: I've tried this approach and I'm getting Row as undefined

Comment: @Pavantej I tried with same and I am able to get row data in console. Screenshot added for same

Comment: Sorry, it's working i'm able to get parent records but how to get child records?

Comment: If you have parent details then you can get all child details from data attribute. Data attribute contains all details with relationship.

Comment: I have tried it's not working actually my parent and child records are not related. Currently, I'm building my JSON primarily through code. So, I'm not sure how to get child records. But if console the Row object it shows like Property: hasChildren Value: true

Comment: @Pavantej You have all data in attribute `gridData `. From this attribute you can get all children.

Comment: I'm getting undefined with gridData

Comment: @Pavantej you are showing `gridData` on tree grid so you should have data in this. If still have confusion then please add your data preparation code so we can check.

Comment: I have added the JSON response over there